# How to do render partial on jQuery ajax success method with rails 3

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm using rails 3.2.1 with jQuery for an ajax call.

My jQuery code is :

```
jQuery.ajax({
  url: "/org_pages",
  data: 'org_id='+ org_id,
  type: "POST",
  success: function(result){                        
    jQuery("#image_center").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'pages/top_link')) %>");
  },
  error: function(){
    alert('Error occured');
  }
});
```

My problem is on the web page the output is showing this  :

```
<%= render :partial => 'pages/top_link', :collection=>@pages %>
```

How it should display my render partial page. :(

Comment: this link solve my problem and my day also


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114220/reload-partial-rails-ajax/6120051#6120051

Answer (score 27, accepted):

try by rendering the partial from the controller as,

```
def method_name
  render :partial => 'some_partial'
end
```

and in js,

```
success: function(result){                      
  jQuery("#image_center").html(result);
}
```

OR ELSE

create a js.erb file corresponding to that action and inside that paste the following:

```
jQuery("#image_center").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'pages/top_link')) %>");
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create this file : /app/views/org_pages/index.js.erb and put this in your file :

```
jQuery("#image_center").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'pages/top_link')) %>");
```

This code will be rendered and executed on success.