# Making a POST request using jQuery's Ajax and Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I want to load a set of objects and render them using Ajax and a `select` element in HTML.  Here is the jQuery I use to make the request:

planner.js

```
$("select.semesterSelect").change(function(){
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/planners/events",
      data: {timeperiod: {id: $(this).find(":selected").val()}},
      success: function(events){
         console.log("success");
      },
      error: function(){
         console.log("error");
      }
   });
});
```

Here is the controller action I'm using to find the objects I want to render:

planners_controller.rb

```
def events
@timeperiod = params[:timeperiod] ? Timeperiod.find(params[:timeperiod][:id]) : Timeperiod.find(Timeperiod.last.id)
@events = Event.where("from_date >= :tp_from_date AND to_date <= :tp_to_date", {tp_from_date: @timeperiod.from_date, tp_to_date: @timeperiod.to_date})
 respond_to do |format|
   format.html
   format.js
 end
end
```

Finally, here is the js.erb file I'm using to render the events (I've commented out the rendering line).

events.js.erb

```
//$("#events_div").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'planners/event')) %>");
console.log("here");
```

When I make a selection using this setup, I get "success" in the js console log.  However, I do not see "here".  When I uncomment out the rendering line, I it doesn't render my new objects.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I corrected the filenames.
Edit 2: Below are links I used to format this code.

"Working with JavaScript in Rails": http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html
"how to do render partial on jquery ajax success method with rails 3": [How to do render partial on jQuery ajax success method with rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11844513/how-to-do-render-partial-on-jquery-ajax-success-method-with-rails-3)

Comment: Does the containing div really have an id attribute of `events_div`?

Comment: Yes.  The problem is events.js.erb is not being called at all.

Comment: Sounds like it is being rendered, since you can log out `"here"` if you remove the first line. Perhaps the issue is in your `planners/event` partial?

Comment: Even if I remove the first line, I do not see `here`, only `success` which is printed by `events.js`.  So far as I can tell, there is no issue with the `planners/event` partial, it renders well in the plain `events.html.erb` file

Comment: I'm not entirely certain, but can a JS rendered template render an HTML partial?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, but my method is a compilation of prescribed methods for handling Ajax calls with Rails.  I've updated the main post to show how I got the formatting for this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by splitting the `planners/events` action into two events as follows:

```
  def events
   @timeperiod = params[:timeperiod] ? Timeperiod.find(params[:timeperiod][:id]) : Timeperiod.find(Timeperiod.last.id)
   @events = Event.where("from_date >= :tp_from_date AND to_date <= :tp_to_date", {tp_from_date: @timeperiod.from_date, tp_to_date: @timeperiod.to_date})
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
    end
  end

  def events2
   @timeperiod = params[:timeperiod] ? Timeperiod.find(params[:timeperiod][:id]) : Timeperiod.find(Timeperiod.last.id)
   @events = Event.where("from_date >= :tp_from_date AND to_date <= :tp_to_date", {tp_from_date: @timeperiod.from_date, tp_to_date: @timeperiod.to_date})
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

As you can see, `events2` renders jQuery and `events` renders html.  I also modified my js function to use the second function.

planner.js

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/planners/events2".
...
```

This executes code in `events2.js.erb`.  This is unwieldily.  Does anyone have a solution that doesn't involve splitting into two different actions like this?  I'd be happy to accept a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

As I know about jQuery/Ajax with rails,

Here you have defined the url

```
url: "/planners/events",
```

so for that you have to defined the events method into planners controller.

and one more thing for get update on view, you have to create a `events.js.erb` file.

Comment: There is an events method in the planners controller and an events.js.erb file.  Check the updated post for correct filenames.

Comment: start server and check again.

Comment: That didn't fix this issue.  Without `format.html`, the page wouldn't render at all and with `format.html`, it gave me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, there could be several causes of the issue:

1. Your Routes may not point to the controller
2. You may not be handling the request correctly on the controller (causing a 500 server error)

I've written this as an answer to give an idea as to how to debug this further:

---

**Routes**

From what you've said, you should have this route setup:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :planners do
    post :events
end
```

Although I don't think this is your problem, it would be beneficial to ensure it's present

---

**Developer Console**

If you're using Chrome / Firefox, you can use the [developer console](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network) (`right-click` > `inspect element` > `network`) to show all the ajax requests for your site

I'd highly recommend you do this to see what the response is. I think your error is caused by the controller causing a 500 internal server error, which you'll not know about unless you look at the network activity & see the `preview` tab

---

**Ajax "Success"**

Just means you've made a connection to the controller, and has received a response. The response could be an error, but Ajax can't tell because each response from Rails is a valid HTML page

I would recommend using the Developer tools `network` tab to see what's going on. If you can relay back some more details about the response, we'll be in a better position to help!

Comment: I had `#get "planners/events"` and `#post "planners/events"` in `config/routes.rb`.  Switching to the `resources` configuration did not fix the error.

Comment: Also, I get a status of 200 when I view the Network tab (I'm using Chrome).